# How to find mean (average) of each 3 values in one column of unknown size using pandas. No Numpy

Tags: pandas, mean

I am trying to figure out how to apply such functions (mean. STD etc) on different values of a CSV file. To keep it simple I put here the example of one column.

```
S08
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
150

D1 = D.loc[:,'S08']

rang = len(D1)
for i in range(rang):
    x = D1.iloc[:,i+2]
    m = x.mean()
    print(m)


time    S08 S09 S15   S37   S38 S39   S41   S45 S49
1       10  5   100    5    145 1500    1   10  99
2       20  15  200    15   135 1400    2   150 99
3       30  25  300    25   125 1300    3   140 99
4       40  35  400    35   115 1200    4   130 99
5       50  45  500    45   105 1100    5   120 99
6       60  55  600    55   95  1000    6   110 99
7       70  65  700    65   85  900     7   100 99
8       80  75  800    75   75  800     8   90  99
9       90  85  900    85   65  700     9   80  99
10     100  95  1000   95   55  600     10  70  99
11     110  105 1100  105   45  500     11  60  99
12     120  115 1200  115   35  400     12  50  99
13     130  125 1300  125   25  300     13  40  99
14     140  135 1400  135   15  200     14  30  99
15     150  145 1500  145   5   100     15  20  99
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqPRl.jpg)

Comment: Is the answer below what you are looking for? Can you put the output of what you want?

Comment: The answer below is fine. But i just need all the means in one column and STD in another column. It means that the mean of S08,S09....S49 in one column and STD of S08,S09....S49  in another column. So in total i get 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` floor divided by `3` and then aggregate columns by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
#create monotonic unique index (0,1,2...) if necessary
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg({'col1':'mean', 'col2':'std'})
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(10,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  0  2  4
2  2  2  2
3  2  1  0
4  0  4  3
5  4  2  0
6  3  1  2
7  3  4  4
8  1  3  4
9  4  3  3

df1 = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg({'A':'mean', 'B':'std'})
print (df1)
          A         B
0  0.666667  1.154701
1  2.000000  1.527525
2  2.333333  1.527525
3  4.000000       NaN

#floor dicide index values for create triple groups
print (df.index // 3)
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg(['mean','std'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)

    A_mean     A_std    B_mean     B_std    C_mean     C_std
0  0.666667  1.154701  1.333333  1.154701  3.000000  1.000000
1  2.000000  2.000000  2.333333  1.527525  1.000000  1.732051
2  2.333333  1.154701  2.666667  1.527525  3.333333  1.154701
3  4.000000       NaN  3.000000       NaN  3.000000       NaN
```

Comment: you used np. Is that possible without NP ?

Comment: Yes, sure ;) Solution was changed

Comment: It is working. But could you please explain a little bit how it works? You even  didnt use any loop./

Comment: I add sample - it group by no column, by Index floor divided by 3, so processes each 3 rows by aggregate functions specifying in dictionary..

Comment: And small advice to future - you get downvotes, because no sample data and mainly no code in your question, please add it for avoiding it.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the advice. I had no idea.  In this case if i had multiple columns then how could i proceed.

Comment: It depends what you need. If need same aggregate function for all columns then `df = df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()`, but if need different each column has to by used in `dictionary` like `agg({'col1':'mean', 'col2':'std', 'col3':'mean', 'col4':'sum'})`

Comment: Check more in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)

Comment: Well, i am trying to find mean and STD of each of these columns putting them in two columns. Input data is in the question above:

Comment: Check last edit - use `list` of functions in `agg`, then get `MultiIndex`, so for flattening columns use `map` + `join`